# Sticky-kit.js not working even in the official example page

Tags: javascript, jquery, sticky

I´m working with sticky-kit for in my web project for a while. Now, I´m developing new functionalities with sticky-kit that are not working. But, the point is even the examples in the sticky-kit official web page are not working for me: https://leafo.net/sticky-kit/#examples. I can see a lot of javascript errors in the console. I´m pretty sure I´m missing something stupid, but I don´t know what.

UPDATE:

I can see these errors in the console:

```
Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

main.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at main.js:3
    at main.js:24

example.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at example.js:5
    at example.js:54
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do anything about it but inform the maintainers of sticky-kit.js that they update there site. As their site is only reachable via https (which is good) they are not allowed to load 3rd party code via http like the do with google fonts or jQuery.

Comment: Nope, they can't. This affects _all_ users that browse to their site. They have to fix it on there end. Maybe you can build the website for your own if you checkout their github repo. Then you could run the site on you localhost (without https) and it could work.

Comment: Ok. I just wanted to check that is not a problem of my computer. I recently updated my OS version and some things broke.